# Suits of tiers - A GW2 themed enigmatic puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, visual

I have created this puzzle quite some time ago in the style of the - then still ongoing - [CiSRA puzzle competition](https://puzzle.cisra.com.au), but very heavily leaning on elements of the computer game Guild Wars 2.

A couple of notes regarding the puzzle

- the puzzle consists only of the picture below
- the solution is a single word or short phrase
- the [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag refers to the fact that this puzzle's theme is heavily influenced by the Guild Wars game. Since I don't expect a lot of people here to know it, I'm including some initial hints below that would be obvious to players of the game. All necessary information can be found online (mostly on the wiki) without ever having played the game.

[image: Suits of Tiers]

**Hint 0** (for people who don't know Guild Wars 2)

> The puzzle shows the in-game symbols of various [crafting materials](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting_material#List_of_crafting_materials) and [sigils](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sigil#List_of_sigils) that are part of the game

**Hint 1**

> Players of the game often will refer to specific grades of a material by 'tier N'. E.g. T5 wood; T3 Blood, ...

**Hint 2**

> Think exaggerated, when trying to decipher the first set of clues

Edit: I'll start adding more hints over time

Comment: Just Ebonhawke?

Comment: @JanIvan nope, it's a good guess, but you're not quite there yet - you're also not yet using all information available. I'll add more hints

Answer (score 2):

My progress

> As the 1st hint states, each of these images is an item in Guild Wars 2, that is commonly abbreviated in the form T[n] [type] to ease communication. 
>  If we take each item's [type], and count to the [n]th letter, we get the following: 
>  
>  T3 En**e**rgy, T2 L**a**pis, T1 **S**cale, T3 Wa**t**er >>> EAST
>  T4 Gla**c**ial, T2 F**i**re, T4 Dus**t**, T4 Chr**y**socola >>> CITY
>  T3 To**p**az, T2 E**a**rth, T3 De**s**troyer, T3 To**t**em >>> PAST
>  T5 Leat**h**er, T3 Am**e**thyst, T3 Ai**r**, T6 WoodL**o**g >>> HERO

With this, I am assuming we are looking for

> The name of a specific city in GW2? I could be wrong though.

Unfortunately, with so little knowledge of GW2, this is as far as I can get for now.

Comment: Very good on the first part! For the second part look a bit into the history of the game and you may find something.

Comment: Ascalon? Ebonhawke? some parts of Elona are technically east of Ebonhawke, but I don't think there are any cities. Not sure how Cantha lines up at all, but Cantha isn't available in GW2 yet.

Comment: or specifically referring to Heroes, here's a list: https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Hero#Recruitment_by_region

Comment: @BenLubar or maybe Amnoon, and hero is reference to story with Kormir.